# Is there a way to log queries on Neo4J like Hibernate?

Tags: nosql, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

So, here is the scenario:

- I have Neo4J server running locally with some data in it
- I have a web app using `spring-data-neo4j`

The following code is based on the example code [Cineasts](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples/cineasts):

```
public interface CrewRepository extends GraphRepository<Crew> {

  Iterable<Crew> findByNameLike(String name);

  @Query("start thinker=node({0}) match thinker-[:crews]-crews return crews")
  Set<Crew> findByThinker(Long thinkerId);

}
```

No news here. The problem is: the query `findByNameLike` doesn't work whereas the `findByThinker` does.

I have modified my log configuration file many times - final version is the one below - but, doesn't matter what I try, I can't see any queries being logged - either on my log file or on the server.

```
<logger name="org.neo4j">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.data.neo4j">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>

<root>
  <priority value="error" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

All I want is the log the queries so I can see if it's a bug on `spring-data-neo4j` or if I'm missing something... I have looked through the documentation of both, code examples and couldn't find anything that specific.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Query loggin will be added to the next snapshot / milestone that is released.

Comment: What does your `Crew` class look like? What do you pass in to findByNameLike and what data have you stored in your Crew objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable query logging by adding the following lines to your log4j.xml:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone lands here looking for how to log queries when Neo4j Server is accessed remotely over the REST API, use

```
<logger name="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestCypherQueryEngine">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

If you're using Spring Data Neo4j and want to see the derived queries corresponding to your DAO methods,

```
<logger name="org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.DerivedCypherRepositoryQuery">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Neither this, nor the other answer does not work for me with log4j2. Is there something different to do with log4j2?